# RESTful api versioning and grouping in doc from Swagger with multiple endpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, api-versioning

I am trying to implement the version options on a MVC dotnet Core app that has API endpoint on it.

The set up i am after is like this

```
 --AiM api
   |_v1
   |_v2
 --RMS api
   |_v1
```

I have it mostly working but the items on v1 are not showing up on v2.  The output is like so

[image]
[image]

But when we get to the version 2 on the `AiM v2` endpoint I only the one item 
[image]

Which is not what i was expecting

I have made a test to get each one showing on its different pages in swagger like this

In **controller**

```
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "aim_v1")]
[Route("aim/v{version:apiVersion}/write/")]
public class aimWriter_v1Controller : Controller
{

    [SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "AiM Departments" })]
    [HttpPost("departments/delete/{id}")]
    public IActionResult departments(string foo)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            results = "edited"
        });
    }

    [SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "AiM Contacts" })]
    [HttpPost("contacts/delete/{id}")]
    public IActionResult contact_delete(string foo)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            results = "edited"
        });
    }

    [SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "AiM Contacts" })]
    [HttpPost("contacts/activate/{id}")]
    public IActionResult contact_activate(string foo)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            results = "edited"
        });
    }
}


[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "aim_v2")]
[Route("aim/v{version:apiVersion}/write/")]
public class aimWriter_v2Controller : Controller
{

    [SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "AiM Contacts" })]
    [HttpPost("contacts/delete/{id}")]
    public IActionResult contact_delete(string foo)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            results = "edited"
        });
    }


}


[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "aim_v1")]
[Route("aim/v{version:apiVersion}/")]
public class aim_v1Controller : Controller
{

    [SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "AiM Rooms" })]
    [HttpPost("rooms")]
    public IActionResult rooms(string foo)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            results = "foo"
        });
    }

    [SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "AiM Buildings" })]
    [HttpPost("buildings/rooms/{id}")]
    public IActionResult building_rooms(string foo)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            results = "foo"
        });
    }

    [SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "AiM Rooms" })]
    [HttpPost("rooms/{id}")]
    public IActionResult room(string foo)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            results = "foo"
        });
    }
}

// set up as just a new endpoint (NOTE: in different controller)
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "rms_v1")]
[Route("rms/v{version:apiVersion}/")]
public class rms_v1Controller : Controller
{
    [SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "RMS Orders" })]
    [HttpPost("set_order/{id}")]
    public IActionResult set_order(string foo)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            results = "foo"
        });
    }

}
```

And in the **Startup.cs**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddApiVersioning(options => {
            options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true ;
            options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(new DateTime(2016, 7, 1));
        });
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {


            c.SwaggerDoc("aim_v1", new Info
            {
                Version = "aim/v1",
                Title = "WSU HTTP API"
            });
            c.SwaggerDoc("aim_v2", new Info
            {
                Version = "aim/v2",
                Title = "WSU HTTP API v2"
            });
            c.SwaggerDoc("rms_v1", new Info
            {
                Version = "rms/v1",
                Title = "WSU HTTP API"
            });




            //Set the comments path for the swagger json and ui.
            var basePath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "project.in.bin.def.xml");
            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
        });

    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {

        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger(o =>
        {
            o.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) => swaggerDoc.Host = httpReq.Host.Value);
            o.RouteTemplate = "doc/{documentName}/scheme.json";
        });

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS etc.), specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.RoutePrefix = "docs";
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/doc/aim_v1/scheme.json", "AiM v1.0.0");
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/doc/rms_v1/scheme.json", "Rms v1.0.0");
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/doc/aim_v2/scheme.json", "AiM v2.0.0");
        });
    }
```

And in the **index.html** for the swagger ui doc template file has

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.JSConfig = JSON.parse('{"SwaggerEndpoints":[{"Url":"/doc/aim_v1/scheme.json","Description":"AiM v1.0.0"},{"Url":"/doc/aim_v2/scheme.json","Description":"AiM v2.0.0"},{"Url":"/doc/rms_v1/scheme.json","Description":"RMS v1.0.0"}],"BooleanValues":["false","true"],"DocExpansion":"list","SupportedSubmitMethods":["get","post","put","delete","patch"],"OnCompleteScripts":[],"OnFailureScripts":[],"ShowRequestHeaders":false,"JsonEditor":false,"OAuth2ClientId":"your-client-id","OAuth2ClientSecret":"your-client-secret-if-required","OAuth2Realm":"your-realms","OAuth2AppName":"your-app-name","OAuth2ScopeSeparator":" ","OAuth2AdditionalQueryStringParams":{}}');

$(function () {

  hljs.configure({
    highlightSizeThreshold: 5000
  });

  // Pre load translate...
  if(window.SwaggerTranslator) {
    window.SwaggerTranslator.translate();
  }
  window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
      url: "/doc/aim_v1/scheme.json",
    dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
    supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post'],
    onComplete: function(swaggerApi, swaggerUi){
      if(typeof initOAuth == "function") {
        initOAuth({
            clientId: "ffff==",
            clientSecret: "bbbb",
            realm: "wsu-api",
            appName: "wsu-api-broker",
            scopeSeparator: " ",
            additionalQueryStringParams: {}
        });
      }

      if(window.SwaggerTranslator) {
        window.SwaggerTranslator.translate();
      }
      _.each(JSConfig.OnCompleteScripts, function (script) {
          $.getScript(script);
      });

    },
    onFailure: function(data) {
      log("Unable to Load SwaggerUI");
    },
    docExpansion: false,
    jsonEditor: false,
    defaultModelRendering: 'schema',
    showRequestHeaders: false
  });

  window.swaggerUi.load();

  function log() {
    if ('console' in window) {
      console.log.apply(console, arguments);
    }
  }
```

});

In order to get the items on the different endpoints I used the `[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "aim_v1")]` on the classes and matched them up in the **Startup.cs** and **index.html** files.  At this point I am unsure where to make my edit to get all of the `[ApiVersion("1.0")]` items show on the `[ApiVersion("2.0")]` as I think the **ApiExplorerSettings** ***GroupName*** is what it locking this up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger not working correctly with multiple versions of ASP.NET WebApi app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46058930/swagger-not-working-correctly-with-multiple-versions-of-asp-net-webapi-app)

Comment: @NarottamGoyal you mean that is the possible duplication.. dates are important lol...

Comment: my bad removed the duplicate flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To integrate everything smoothly, you also need to add the official [API Explorer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer/) package for API Versioning. This will collate all of the API version information for you in a way that Swagger will understand. The official Swagger/Swashbuckle integration [wiki topic](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/Swashbuckle-Integration) has additional details and examples.

The setup will look like:

```
public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
{
    // note: this option is only necessary when versioning by url segment.
    // the SubstitutionFormat property can be used to control the format of the API version
    services.AddMvcCore().AddVersionedApiExplorer(
        options =>
        {
            options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
            options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
        } );

    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddApiVersioning();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(
        options =>
        {
            var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>();

            foreach ( var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions )
            {
                options.SwaggerDoc( description.GroupName, CreateInfoForApiVersion( description ) );
            }

            options.IncludeXmlComments( XmlCommentsFilePath );
        } );
}

public void Configure( IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider )
{
    app.UseMvc();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(
        options =>
        {
            foreach ( var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions )
            {
                options.SwaggerEndpoint( $"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json", description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant() );
            }
        } );
}

static string XmlCommentsFilePath
{
    get
    {
        var basePath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;
        var fileName = typeof( Startup ).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name + ".xml";
        return Path.Combine( basePath, fileName );
    }
}

static Info CreateInfoForApiVersion( ApiVersionDescription description )
{
    var info = new Info()
    {
        Title = $"Sample API {description.ApiVersion}",
        Version = description.ApiVersion.ToString(),
        Description = "A sample application with Swagger, Swashbuckle, and API versioning.",
        Contact = new Contact() { Name = "Bill Mei", Email = "bill.mei@somewhere.com" },
        TermsOfService = "Shareware",
        License = new License() { Name = "MIT", Url = "https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT" }
    };

    if ( description.IsDeprecated )
    {
        info.Description += " This API version has been deprecated.";
    }

    return info;
}
```

Comment: I have a very similar approach as these code snippets.
Issue is ApiVersionDescription.GroupName is always v1 or v2 but does NOT contain the GroupName defined in the ApiExplorerSettings

Comment: @EricBDev, in API Versioning 5.0+, `ApiExplorerSettingsAttribute.GroupName` will be honored if it is explicitly set. You should note, however, that this puts all the onus of grouping on you. The only sensible ways of grouping are by API version or whatever you explicitly configure. Any other method is likely best suited with a custom **IApiDescriptionProvider** that collates things the way you want.

Comment: Still with .net core 3.1, I eventually found the proper solution in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60475009/grouping-and-versioning-not-working-well-together-in-swagger-in-asp-net-core-3-1

Comment: `Disclaimer: I am the author of API Versioning`

Yes, that approach can work, but I would still recommend using a custom **IApiDescriptionProvider**. That is a simpler solution IMHO. That is how API versioning collates things in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

A full working answer is in that question:
[Grouping and Versioning not working well together in swagger in asp.net core 3.1 web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60475009/grouping-and-versioning-not-working-well-together-in-swagger-in-asp-net-core-3-1)

As the author said, the DocInclusionPredicate in AddSwaggerGen in the ConfigureServices is doing the trick to map the proper controller to the wanted swagger file.

Comment: I've provided another answer to the referenced question that demonstrates how to create a custom **IApiDescriptionProvider**. It has the added benefit of continuing to work when Swashbuckle changes, you change OpenAPI document generators, or need to use the information in another context (ex: test automation).