# Swagger not supporting minor versions ASP.NET Webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger

I am developing a webapi which supports multiple versions. Currently I have three versions 1.0, 1.1 and 2.0. I have gone through the solution for multi version support in swagger and implemented it from the below link

[swagger not working properly with multiversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46058930/swagger-not-working-correctly-with-multiple-versions-of-asp-net-webapi-app)

The code works fine but the problem is swagger is not loading with version 1.1. It works fine with version 1.0 and 2.0. 
[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `http://localhost:64754/swagger/docs/v1.1` actually exist? E.g. can you see it if you navigate to this URL in your browser?

Comment: yes i can navigate to the url in the bowser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution. It's due to swagger.config instance problem. Solved by adding the assembly  `[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]` in swagger.config and moved all the versioning code to webapi.config. Not sure why this has to be done for minor versions to work but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, `http://localhost:64754/swagger/docs/v1.1` would return a 404 error while `http://localhost:64754/swagger/docs/v1` or `http://localhost:64754/swagger/docs/v2` worked fine.

The way I fixed it was to add this to the `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
    </modules>
    ...
</system.webServer>
```