# Grouping and Versioning not working well together in swagger in asp.net core 3.1 web api

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle, api-versioning

I'm using **Asp.Net Core 3.1** to build my API. I'm using swagger to generate document for my API. I decided to do grouping on my swagger document based on controller. So I ended up doing like this,

**Startup - ConfigureServices:**

```cs
options.SwaggerDoc(
    "LibraryOpenAPISpecificationCategories",
    ...
```

**Startup - Configure:**

```cs
options.SwaggerEndpoint(
    "/swagger/LibraryOpenAPISpecificationCategories/swagger.json",
    "Library API (Categories)");
```

**Controller:**

```cs
[Route("api/categories")]
[ApiController]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "LibraryOpenAPISpecificationCategories")]
public class CategoriesController : ControllerBase
```

Until this point everything was working fine. When I added versioning the Swagger document stopped displaying the methods in the controller. I was trying to bring grouping inside version so that each version will have the groups like,

V1 -> LibraryOpenAPISpecificationCategories

V1 -> LibraryOpenAPISpecificationItems

V2 -> LibraryOpenAPISpecificationCategories

V2 -> LibraryOpenAPISpecificationItems

Here is what I did,

**Startup - ConfigureServices:**

```cs
services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(options =>
{
    options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VV";
});

services.AddApiVersioning(options =>
{
    options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
    options.ReportApiVersions = true;
});

var apiVersionDescriptionProvider =
    services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>();

services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    foreach (var description in apiVersionDescriptionProvider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
    {
        options.SwaggerDoc(
            $"LibraryOpenAPISpecificationCategories{description.GroupName}",
            ...
```

**Startup - Configure:**

```cs
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    foreach (var description in apiVersionDescriptionProvider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
    {
        options.SwaggerEndpoint(
            $"/swagger/LibraryOpenAPISpecificationCategories{description.GroupName}/swagger.json",
            $"Library API (Categories) {description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant()}");
```

**Controller:**

```cs
[Route("api/categories")]
[ApiController]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "LibraryOpenAPISpecificationCategories")]
public class CategoriesController : ControllerBase
```

No error is displayed in swagger document. Please assist me on where I'm going wrong. Am I missing anything?

Comment: looks like I'm missing `DocInclusionPredicate`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some analysis, I figured out that I missed `DocInclusionPredicate` in `AddSwaggerGen` in my `ConfigureServices`.

Here is how I resolved,

```cs
options.DocInclusionPredicate((documentName, apiDescription) =>
{
    var actionApiVersionModel = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor
    .GetApiVersionModel(ApiVersionMapping.Explicit | ApiVersionMapping.Implicit);

    var apiExplorerSettingsAttribute = (ApiExplorerSettingsAttribute)apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata.First(x => x.GetType().Equals(typeof(ApiExplorerSettingsAttribute)));

    if (actionApiVersionModel == null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (actionApiVersionModel.DeclaredApiVersions.Any())
    {
        return actionApiVersionModel.DeclaredApiVersions.Any(v =>
        $"{apiExplorerSettingsAttribute.GroupName}v{v.ToString()}" == documentName);
    }
    return actionApiVersionModel.ImplementedApiVersions.Any(v =>
        $"{apiExplorerSettingsAttribute.GroupName}v{v.ToString()}" == documentName);
});
```

Hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: thanks for your addition, it helped me to get a working solution with multiple swagger docs!

Comment: This will work, but I would recommend using a custom **IApiDescriptionProvider** to recollate the **ApiDescription** instances. The API Explorer only supports a single level of organization (e.g. `GroupName`). It logically makes sense that this should be the API version by default. Until API Versioning 5.0+, any explicit any explicit value you put in `ApiExplorerSettings.GroupName` was overwritten. While you can (now) provide your own group name, putting those all in a single OpenAPI document will depend on how you are versioning. You typically need 1 document per API version.

Comment: Ultimately, API Versioning's own **IApiDescriptionProvider** only provides to basic functions. **1.** Add a parameter descriptor for the API version parameter. **2.** Set and collate API descriptions by API version. Creating your own provider that reorganizes things at the end doesn't take much work.

Answer (score 0):

Since a few people asked for this in various places, here's how you'd implement a custom **IApiDescriptionProvider**. It simply updates the `ApiDescription.GroupName` at the end of processing. This will work completely independent of Swashbuckle or any other OpenAPI/Swagger document generator:

```cs
public class CollateApiDescriptionProvider : IApiDescriptionProvider
{
    readonly IOptions<ApiExplorerOptions> options;

    public CollateApiDescriptionProvider( IOptions<ApiExplorerOptions> options ) =>
        this.options = options;

    public int Order => 0;

    public void OnProvidersExecuting( ApiDescriptionProviderContext context ) { }

    public void OnProvidersExecuted( ApiDescriptionProviderContext context )
    {
        var results = context.Results;
        var format = options.Value.GroupNameFormat;
        var text = new StringBuilder();

        for ( var i = 0; i < results.Count; i++ )
        {
            var result = results[i];
            var action = result.ActionDescriptor;
            var version = result.GetApiVersion();
            var groupName = action.GetProperty<ApiDescriptionActionData>()?.GroupName;

            text.Clear();

            // add the formatted API version according to the configuration
            text.Append( version.ToString( format, null ) )

            // if there's a group name, prepend it
            if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( groupName ) )
            {
                text.Insert( 0, ' ' );
                text.Insert( 0, groupName );
            }

            result.GroupName = text.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

To register your new provider, add it to the service collection:

```cs
services.TryAddEnumerable(
    ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IApiDescriptionProvider, CollateApiDescriptionProvider>() );
```

> NOTE: this should occur **after** `services.AddApiVersioning()`

You can get as creative as you want with the group names, but be aware that you cannot create multiple levels of grouping. It simply isn't supported out-of-the-box. In most cases, you can only have a single OpenAPI/Swagger document per API version. This is because URLs must be unique within the document.

It is *technically* possible to group on multiple levels, but this would require a number of changes to the UI and document generation process. I've only ever seen a handful of people willing to put that much effort in. They effectively created their own UIs and documentation generation backend.

Answer (score 0):

```
builder.Services.AddApiVersioning( options =>
{
    options.ReportApiVersions = true;
    options.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    options.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion( 1, 0 );
} )
.AddMvc()
.AddApiExplorer(options =>
{
    options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
    options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
    options.FormatGroupName = ( group, version ) => $"{group} - {version}";
} );
```

try this one.
"FormatGroupName" is the trick you need